# Ubuntu 22.10 freezes

Tags: laptop, screen, freeze, 22.10

After some amount of time working on my laptop Ubuntu unexpectedly freezes. The screen is not responding, mouse not moving, then after couple of seconds the screen turns off and back on to the state before with the system not responding.

Laptop model: Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ACL6

CPU: Ryzen 7 5700U

The laptop itself is in a good condition, it was bought 1 year ago.

Don't think it's a hardware problem, cause it appeared right after I've updated to 22.10.

Comment: Please, check system logs and add any information you consider relevant to this problem directly into your question above by [edit]ing it.

Comment: How much time 5 minutes, 5 hours?

Comment: @David the minimal time is probably like 15 mins, the maximum is 2 hours

Comment: To me this seems like a hardware issue, and I'd suspect the laptop's motherboard. It might be useful to post some more information about the laptop's make and model, how old it is and whether it's in good condition. Some software things to check (and add to the post) might be the power-saving settings and temperature levels - as these are things that might 'kick in' suddenly and then some bug interrupts the recovery and forces a reset. Also in case it is a problem with the display manager, does ctrl+alt+f2 bring up a working terminal login or is the keyboard totally unresponsive?

Comment: @FedKad thx, will try to reproduce and check logs for that particular time

Comment: thx for the help, seems I've found out a reason while checking logs, it's related to amdgpu issues

Comment: @evild4ve the system becomes totally not responsible

Comment: @IvanMarkevich, googling "Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ACL6 freezes" this seems to be a common problem with the make and model. Does it do it both with the power cable plugged in and unplugged? And are there any bios settings available for temperature protection?

Comment: I have a similar issue and I also suspect AMD GPU. On my side it is related to the slack app. I uninstalled it now and installed the .deb version and had no crash since then. Laptop is a HP Probook 455 G8 with Ryzen 7 5800U

Comment: @Bob thx man, as for me, I've just downgraded linux kernel back to that one which Ubuntu 22.04 was using (don't remember the kernel version)

Comment: I'm seeing this on an HP Zbook Fury 16 G9, 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12950HX with 64GB memory. Mouse freezes or become very laggy. Then suddenly it will process a bunch of mouse events very rapidly. System is 98% idle.